# Accessing Current Page Information in Safari 12 Extension Popover

Tags: swift, safari, safari-extension, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm trying to get the active tab's page information to be displayed in a popover. I'm able to get it to show the URL or Title of the page currently, but it requires opening and closing the extension popover twice.

I believe it's because to get that information, the below code relies on `completionHandler` which makes it async.

```swift
SFSafariApplication.getActiveWindow { (window) in
    window?.getActiveTab { (tab) in
        tab?.getActivePage(completionHandler: { (page) in
            page?.getPropertiesWithCompletionHandler( { (properties) in
                self.pageTitle = properties?.title ?? "Unknown"
                self.ActivePageTitle.stringValue =  self.pageTitle
            })
        })
    }
}
```

The first time you open the popover it shows a blank text region, but the second time it will have loaded in the information before and shows it correctly.

I've tried running it in `viewDidLoad()` but that only fires the first time the popover is opened.

When running it in `viewWillAppear()` I get the below error:

```
pid(17738)/euid(501) is calling TIS/TSM in non-main thread environment,
ERROR : This is NOT allowed. Please call TIS/TSM in main thread!!!
```

I thought maybe switching the extension to use a `command` instead would work but then realized you can't programatically open the popover window.

Do I have to switch to `UITableView` or something that has a `reloadData()` function to run once the async request for data is complete?

MacOS 10.14.4 | Safari 12.1 | Xcode 10.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your UI code on the main thread. Wrap the page title updates in DispatchQueue. I had almost the exact same issue, and this worked for me.

```
SFSafariApplication.getActiveWindow { (window) in
    window?.getActiveTab { (tab) in
        tab?.getActivePage(completionHandler: { (page) in
            page?.getPropertiesWithCompletionHandler( { (properties) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.pageTitle = properties?.title ?? "Unknown"
                    self.ActivePageTitle.stringValue =  self.pageTitle
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

To give proper credit, I found the answer while digging through this code on GitHub (check out the `updateDataLabels()` method):
https://github.com/otzbergnet/tabCount/blob/master/tabCount%20Extension/SafariExtensionViewController.swift

Answer (score -1):

You can get **SFSafariPageProperties** object in **SafariExtensionHandler** and use this object in **SafariExtensionViewController**.

```
- (void)popoverWillShowInWindow:(SFSafariWindow *)window {
    [window getActiveTabWithCompletionHandler:^(SFSafariTab *activeTab) {
        [activeTab getActivePageWithCompletionHandler:^(SFSafariPage *page) {
            [page getPagePropertiesWithCompletionHandler:^(SFSafariPageProperties *properties) {
                // Now you can use "properties" in viewController using shareObject
            }];
        }];
    }];
}
```

Now need to get properties of **SFSafariPage** again in viewWillAppear.

Comment: That appears to just be Objective-C code for what I've already posted in the question? I don't have trouble getting the information, I have trouble getting it in there before the popover shows or to update the open popover with the information once I have it.